# Xamarin.IOS can upload only 3 pics from gallery. Is any limitation in IOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, file-upload

I am developing an IOS app and i have a very weird problem. I select multiple images from gallery and upload them to our server. It works perfectly up to a point. I can upload even 10 files from the app directory (included in the project) with no problem at all, but when I try to upload multiple files from the phone gallery only 3 pictures gets uploaded. I get no error message, no warning, nothing. Seems IOS "thinks" it has sent all images and uploaded them but whatever I do, only 3 images gets uploaded. I tried with different images in different sizes. Always only 3 images uploaded. Maybe I could save all images into the app folder and upload them from there, I didn't try but I would like to know if any limitation in the phone gallery access or anything what could cause this behaviour.
 The code I use to upload images:

```
   Int32 i = 0;

   var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
   var jobpics = realm.All<JobPicturesR>().Where(d => d.Id > -1);
   Console.WriteLine("jobpics count: " + jobpics.Count().ToString()); 
   //-- 10 images in the JobPics their path refers to gallery

        foreach (var Pic in jobpics)
        {
            i++;
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var uri = new Uri("ourwebapiurl/UploadPic/" + JobID.ToString());

                webClient.UploadFileAsync(uri, "POST", Pic.FileName, i);

                Console.WriteLine("upload started ({0})", Pic.FileName); 
               //-- all 10 images upload started properly 

                webClient.UploadProgressChanged += HandleUploadProgressChanged; 

             //-- i see progress for all 10 images and all finish with 100% uploaded but still only 3 appear on server.

            }
        }
```

Comment: No limitations. How do you get the image from the gallery?

Comment: I use ELCImagePickerViewController to select the images. I get the path of the images into a list what I can push out to the console, also I load those images from the list into a collectionview and they works fine except the upload. Now I tried, if I copy the selected pictures into a temp folder I can upload them without problem. It just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: You should probably use PHAsset to get the images from your paths. This way you are sure that the images are locally on the device and not only on iCloud.

Comment: After lots of researching and testing i am pretty sure eclimagepicker messes up something. I did a workaround by copy the images to a tmp folder first.